# Is using a giant OR regex inefficent in python?

Tags: python, regex, multithreading, string, performance

Simple question, is using a giant OR regex inefficent in python.  I am building a script to search for bad files.  I have a source file that contains 50 or so "signatures" so far.  The list is in the form of:

```
 Djfsid
 LJflsdflsdf
 fjlsdlf
 fsdf
 .
 .
 .
```

There are no real "consistancies" so optomizing the list by removing "duplicates" or checking for "is one entry a substring of another entry" won't do much.

I basically wan't to OS walk down a directory, open a file, check for the signature, close and move on.

To speed things up I will break the list up into 50/n different sublists where N is the number of cores and have a thread do work on a few entries of the list.

Would using a giant regex `re.search('(entry1|entry2|entry3....|entryK)', FILE_CONTENTS)` or a giant `for i in xrange(0,NUM_SUBENTRIES)...if subentry[i] in FILE_CONTENTS...` be better off?

Also is this a good way to multithread?  This is unix so multiple threads can work on the same file at the same time.  Will disk access basically bottelneck me to the point where multithreading is useless?

Comment: Each time you use `in` it needs to iterate through the contents of the string.  If you have many strings to search for it would be horribly inefficient to use `in`.

Comment: When did 50 become a "giant" number?

Answer (score 3):

> Also is this a good way to multithread?

Not really.

> Will disk access basically bottelneck me to the point where multithreading is useless?

Correct.

You might want to look closely at `multiprocessing`.

1. A worker `Process` should do the OS.walk and put the file names into a Queue.
2. A pool of worker `Process` instances.  Each will get a file name from the Queue, open it, check the signature and enqueue results into a "good" Queue and a "bad" Queue.  Create as many of these as it takes to make the CPU 100% busy.
3. Another worker `Process` instance can dequeue good entries and log them.
4. Another worker `Process` instance can dequeue bad entries and delete or rename or whatever is supposed to happen.  This can interfere with the os.walk.  A possibility is to log these into a "do this next" file which is processed *after* the os.walk is finished.

Comment: For a single disk the "bottleneck" may be true. For NAS / RAID - not so much. Anyway, +1.

Comment: Actually, it's the OS-level I/O that's the bottleneck.  All the threads share the I/O interface, and that's the real bottleneck.  Lots of I/O (all those files, plus the os.walk) means lots of processes will do better than many threads in one process.

Comment: @SLott: Ah, makes sense. I suppose things change a bit with event-based (asynchronuous) IO but I'm not sure if Python supports such a thing for the file system (node.js does).

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the machine you are using. If you use the machine's maximum capaticy, it will slow down, of course. I think the best way to find out is to try.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about optimisation.

50 data points is tiny compared to what your computer can manage, so you'll probably waste a lot of your time, and make your program more complicated.

Comment: Some directories have millions of files.  We have a crude version of this using grep and it goes pretty darn slow.

What is faster though?  Regex or giant for..in

EDIT:  Why multiprocess vs multithread?  Doesn't the OS just context switch threads in\out and if possible run them on multiple cores the same as it would concurrent processes?

Comment: @Chris Not so much in Python, as the GIL enforces single-threading of the Python interpreter itself.

Comment: I'm slightly confused now. I assumed there were only 50 files?

Comment: @Ink-Jet

There are 50 "signatures".  Each signature is ran on each file.  There can be millions of files.  If the file contains one or more signautures it is flagged and reported.

I see where the inefficency could be in my application as I would open and close the file multiple times (one for each thread).  Thanks for the suggestions about multiprocessing